# Como configurar um certificado SSL para um aplicativo que é executado no Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express.js, https

Como configurar um certificado SSL para um aplicativo que é executado no Express?

Estou tentando configurar o servidor Express que criei, para passar o certificado SSL e ir de http para https.

Eu li a documentação do Express, mas não consigo encontrar a solução. Eles propuseram coisas para mim como o Lets Encrypt, mas ele não suporta o Node.js. Eu não sei se devo modificar o arquivo hosts, que eu já modifiquei para executar o aplicativo, ou o que tenho que fazer. Eu vi um formulário, mas ele só funciona no sistema Unix. Eu mostro a maneira em que eu configurei o arquivo do servidor, caso eles possam me ajudar, levou três dias procurando maneiras de fazê-lo sem sucesso. Os que eu vi não suportam o Node.js. Obrigado

> Citação
>   Eu edito de novo:
>   Perdoe, esqueça de dizer que meu objetivo é criar o certificado para um aplicativo no qual você pode fazer o registro no Facebook e tentei os métodos que meus colegas gentilmente ofereceram, mas não funcionou, graças à nova política do Facebook.
>   Se você tiver outra ideia, meu domínio seria michaelgram.test
>   obrigada e perdoe o inconveniente, por não fazer bem a pergunta.
>
> ```js
> let express = require('express');
> let aws = require('aws-sdk');
> let multer = require('multer');
> let multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
> let ext = require('file-extension');
> let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
> let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
> let expressSession = require('express-session');
> let passport = require('passport');
> let michaelgram = require('michaelgram-client');
> let auth = require('./auth')
> let config = require('./config');
> let port = process.env.PORT || 5050;
>
> let client = michaelgram.createClient(config.client);
>
> let s3 = new aws.S3({
>   accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKey,
>   secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretKey
> });
>
> let storage = multerS3({
>   s3: s3,
>   bucket: 'michaelgram',
>   acl: 'public-read',
>   metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
>     cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname })
>   },
>   key: function (req, file, cb) {
>     cb(null, +Date.now() + '.' + ext(file.originalname))
>   }
> });
>
>
> let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('picture');
>
> let app = express();
>
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
> app.use(cookieParser());
> app.use(expressSession({
>   secret: config.secret,
>   resave: false,
>   saveUninitialized: false
> }))
> app.use(passport.initialize())
> app.use(passport.session())
> app.set('view engine', 'pug');
> app.use(express.static('public'));
>
> passport.use(auth.localStrategy);
> passport.use(auth.facebookStrategy);
> passport.deserializeUser(auth.deserializeUser);
> passport.serializeUser(auth.serializeUser);
>
> app.get('/', function (req, res) {
>   res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram' });
> })
>
> app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
>   res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram - Signup' });
> })
>
> app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
>   let user = req.body;
>   client.saveUser(user, function (err, usr) {
>     if (err) return res.status(500).send(err.message)
>     debugger
>     res.redirect('/signin');
>   });
> });
>
> app.get('/signin', function (req, res) {
>   res.render('index', { title: 'Michaelgram - Signin' });
> })
>
> app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
>   successRedirect: '/',
>   failureRedirect: '/signin'
> }));
>
> app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
>
> app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
>   successRedirect: '/',
>   failureRedirect: '/signin'
> }));
>
> function ensureAuth (req, res, next) {
>   if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
>     return next()
>   }
>
>   res.status(401).send({ error: 'not authenticated' })
> }
>
> app.get('/api/pictures', function (req, res, next) {
>   let pictures = [ ];
>
>   setTimeout(function () {
>     res.send(pictures);
>   }, 2000)
> });
>
> app.post('/api/pictures', ensureAuth,function (req, res) {
>   upload(req, res, function (err) {
>     if (err) {
>       return res.send(500, "Error uploading file");
>     }
>     res.send('File uploaded');
>   })
> })
>
> app.get('/api/user/:username', (req, res) => {
>   const user = {
>     username: 'miguelito',
>     avatar: '',
>     pictures: [  ]
>   }
>
>   res.send(user);
> })
>
> app.get('/:username', function (req, res) {
>   res.render('index', { title: `Michaelgram - ${req.params.username}` });
> })
>
> app.get('/:username/:id', function (req, res) {
>   res.render('index', { title: `Michaelgram - ${req.params.username}` });
> })
>
> app.listen(port, function (err) {
>   if (err) return console.log('Hubo un error'), process.exit(1);
>
>   console.log('Michaelgram escuchando en el puerto 5050');
> })
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Tenho um exemplo que utiliza tanto http e https. Desde a versão 3 do express você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('keys/key.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('keys/cert.crt', 'utf8');


var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// your express configuration here
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.send('hello');
});

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log("JSON Server is running on  http://localhost:" + 8080);
});
httpsServer.listen(8443, function () {
    console.log("JSON Server is running on  https://localhost:" + 8443);
});
```

Você só precisa do `key.key` e `cert.crt` para funcionar em sua maquina.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1):

Esse vídeo o autor ensinar a fazer o deploy de uma aplicação node com ssl e nginx: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kR06NoSzAXY

Tem o blog do cara com os comandos para copia e cola, e junto o link do video:
https://code.lengstorf.com/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean/

Explicando o que você vai fazer:

Instalar e configurar o node, seu db e o seu app normalmente;

Vai instalar o certbot;

Como o certbot não reconhece o node, você vai ter que usar algo que ele conheça, no caso o Nginx https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx

Ele atua como balanceador de carga e proxy reverso para as requisições e o melhor eh o fato dele trabalhar com o certbot.

Pelo o Nginx vc vai mandar que as requisições na porta 80 para o seu app na porta 443 que esta com  o SSL, no links ele ensina a tirar um A+ na configuracao do SSL.

Comment: Obrigado, o computador onde trabalho foi quebrado, quando resolvi, começo a tentar. Obrigado